# how to upload blob to server using axios?

Tags: javascript, php, axios

Instead of downloading the blob I want to upload it to a server
I have tried this code and to no luck it didnt work
`

```
recorder.onstop = () => {
  
            /* Convert the recorded audio to 
               blob type mp4 media */
            let blobData = new Blob(data, { type: 'video/mp4' });
  
            // Convert the blob data to a url
            let url = URL.createObjectURL(blobData)
  
            // Assign the url to the output video tag and anchor 
            output.src = url
            anc.href = url
            var formData = new FormData();
            
            formData.append("yawas", blobData);
            
            var url2 = "yati.php";
            axios.post(url, formData, {
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                        }
                    })

                    .then(function(res) {
                        alert("success")
                        

                    })
                    .catch(function(error) {
                        alert("error");
                    })
        };
```

`

and if try this instead
`

```
formData.append("yawas", blobData.files[0]);
```

`
I get this kind of error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') at recorder.onstop.

help